# Method "AddForce()" isn't working on my object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I tried to add force on the object called 'simple banana' but it isn't working. There is my code :

```
simpleBanana.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.back * 10000f, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Insert "Debug.Log (" ... ");" on the next line works. The mass of the object is 1, the object is not kinematic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First and most important:** this way you are getting rigidbody will cause low performance.
GetComponent is a very expensive method, never do it on Update, do it in void Setup, saving it to an object of RigidBody type, like in the API reference:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

**Second:**
I think it can be a reference problem.
I had a lot of trouble with it when I was starting.
Be sure simpleBanana is the object which contains the RigidBody.
If your reference to that RigidBody is not dragging it and dropping it, be sure to navigate at simpleBanana before applying GetComponent.

Like if your script in on simplePotato, and you trying to access simpleBanana, do something like this:

```
RigidBody simpleBanana = GameObject.Find('simpleBanana').GetComponent<RigidBody>();
```

or if simpleBanana is child of simplePotato:

```
RigidBody simpleBanana = this.transform.GetChild(index_of_the_child).GetComponent<RigidBody>();
```

After getting the reference right, you can add whatever force you want.

But remember to get components only on void Setup.

Comment: I found the solution of my problem! Sometimes problems really easy but you can't find the solution. 'simpleBanana' is a prefab of bananas!) Your comment about perfomance is really good.

Comment: Great! haha... It's true, it's very common to overestimate a problem and spend a lot of time in it when it's too simple haha.. it happens